# Vertical Row spacing in QTreeWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` which is populated with custom widgets. I retrieve the item type from an external API, it may be a text value, a numeric value or whatever.
Depending on the type, I provide different controls to the `QTreeWidgetItem`. For example a `QLabel` for textual input, a `QSpinBox` for numeric values and so on.

This is done via the following code:

```
for (GenApi::INode * poNode : oNodeList)  // iterate over a list of items   which i want to represent in the treewidget 
{
QTreeWidgetItem * poRootItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(poTree); //poTree is a   QTreeWidget
poRootItem->setText(0, poNode->GetDisplayName().c_str());
poTree->addTopLevelItem(poRootItem);                        // add as category

GenApi::NodeList_t oInnerNodes;
poNode->GetChildren(oInnerNodes);

for (GenApi::INode * poInnerNode : oInnerNodes)             // each of those nodes may have innter child nodes
{
    QTreeWidgetItem * poItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    CNodeItemBase * poNodeUI = NULL;

    if (GenApi::CIntegerPtr(poInnerNode) != NULL)
        poNodeUI = new CNodeItemInteger(*poInnerNode, poTree);  //CNodeItem... inherits from QWidget and takes the tree as parent

    else if (GenApi::CStringPtr(poInnerNode) != NULL)
        poNodeUI = new CNodeItemString(*poInnerNode, poTree);

    // more possibilities go here....

    if (poNodeUI != NULL)
    {
        poRootItem->addChild(poItem);
        poItem->setText(0, poNodeUI->GetDisplayName().c_str());  // set text of the item
        poTree->setItemWidget(poItem, 1, poNodeUI->m_poControl); // set label/spinbox as widget of the treeitem  
    }
}
}
```

The code works, but the resulting TreeWidget has a problem:

[image]

The resulting TreeWidgetItem has a lot of spacing which makes the TreeWidget hard to read/iterate visually. Is there a fast and easy way to provide something like a QSizePolicy which shrinks the Items? I have tried every combination, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: have you tried setting `verticalHeaderDefaultSectionSize`?

Comment: No, please elaborate, i did not find any solid information on that property.

Comment: it's called `verticalHeaderDefaultSectionSize` in Designer, in code you probably have to use `table->verticalHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(...)`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `contentsMargins` for your item widgets?

Comment: Setting the headerDefault section is definitely not the thing im looking for. it just sets the horizontal default width of a column. I want to decrease the height of a whole row.

Comment: @JonHarper THANKS! Setting the contentsMargin for the Layout inside my itemwidget did the trick.

Comment: @haf It's a weak effort that I'll improve after work (and coffee), but I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using widgets with a layout, make sure to call [`setContentsMargins`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) on the layout with smaller/appropriate values (the default is six pixels on each edge, despite what the docs say).